# Fill two different lists using one source list that has all the data in python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, automation

This code is working properly, and I am able to print the users I scraped. However, my goal here is to split the list with all the names and put just the first one in the `users_involved`(which later will be a column) and the second in the `users_involved2`(also a column).
So the final result would be 2 columns with each user names that was scraped in the list `user_name`. I tried to use a local list and get only the [0] and [1] for each column and it worked, but when I ran bigger inputs, it crashed saying `list_index out of range`. Someone has a suggestion? PS: The size represents the size of the DF, so I am populating this list and them create a COL.
Big thanks for taking the time to read this problem*

```
'''Loop bootom elements to find Users and Clients'''
        user_name = [None] * size
        users_involved = [None] * size
        users_involved_2 = [None] * size
        
        elements_process = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ElementIwasLooking")
        for el in elements_process:
            links = el.find_elements_by_css_selector('p')
            for phrase in links:
                if (phrase.text.startswith("User:")):
                    user_name[i] = phrase.text[10:]
                    users_involved[i] = user_name[i]
                    print(users_involved[i])
```

Comment: Where is your i comming from? Do you mean something like: user_name.append(phrase.text[10:0]) ?

Comment: Sorry! This code is within a for loop which iterates all the csv lines, so the i means for that line in the csv I will get the user_name_1 and user_name_2 . Now I am doing only for 2 or 1 case and verify if I got the right user for the right line

Comment: I suspect your `i` grows larger than `size`. As an aside, `users_involved[i] = user_name[i] means the two lists will be identical - is this what you want?

Comment: The question I made is really confusing, sorry for that, I was able to solved it. The main idea is, scrape everything to a list, and then I split this list in two lists, the first one gets the element 0, and the second list gets the element 1. Therefore will became 2 colums with names, 1 line in csv has 1 col with name A and the other col has a name B. I need this because I will automate this names in the future.  Thanks for the repply